# I am getting a 'org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge' using 2 different transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the Spring Data JPA Repository methods deleteAll() and saveAll(List) in 2 different methods and transactions in a service class. The saveAll(List) method is called to repopulate the table after the deleteAll() call, but I keep getting an org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge error.

```
@Service
ServiceClass
{

   @Autowired MyRepository repository;

   public void test()
   {
       List<myEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
       //code to populate list

       clearTable();
       populateTable(entities);
   }

   @Modifying
   @Transactional
   private void clearTable()
   {
       repository.deleteAll();
   }

   @Modifying
   @Transactional
   private void populateTable(List<myEntity> entities)
   {
       repository.saveAll(entities);
   }

}

//Repository class
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<myEntity, Long>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal implementation of delete in CrudRepository is as

```
@Transactional
    public void delete(T entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
        em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
    }
```

Before an entity removed, this entity must be manage state. We can use some of the function merge,  find, etc. Note : After EntityManager is closed, all the entities of its will be detached.

So do a commit after you delete